# launch a node within another node

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I have two nodes: A and B implemented in C++. Now I want Node A to be launched (by the program, not by users' input in the terminal) within the execution of Node B that is launched by users in the terminal. Is there a ROS way to do this? Or should I just encode a shell command in B's source code to launch A, like executing a shell command in C++ programs?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11162/launch-a-node-within-another-node/) by [HZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/1054/hz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2011-09-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The usual ROS way is running them both from a [roslaunch](http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch) script.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-09-10**:
This will bring up A and B at the beginning, and then B can designed to idle until it is contacted, thus not providing significant overhead.  This also has the advantage that it decreases issues like latency at startup.